# Refresh interactive grid based on select list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have two select lists:

Select list -> Customers 
Select list -> Parties

(Used Cascading LOVS to link Customers select list with Parties select list)

I wonder is it possible to refresh interactive grid based on selection on Parties select list?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about IG. But I did the same for IR(I think it should work for IG too). Just define an 'on Change' DA for the select list. And in the true action ,select 'refresh' and select the region as your IG. The IG will be refreshed each time your value on select list is changed.